# Stratified Sampling in Python: wrong final sample size?

Tags: python, statistics, resampling, statistics-bootstrap

First time posting here.

I am using this line to get a stratified sample of my DataSet, using the variable TamañoMuestral = 0.05

```
DataFrameMAE = DatosPoblacionales.groupby(NombreDeEstrato, group_keys=False).apply(lambda x:x.sample(frac=TamañoMuestral))
```

And using this other line to get a simple random sample of it:

```
DataFrameMAS = DatosPoblacionales.sample(frac=TamañoMuestral, replace=True)
```

I want to compare both samples.

However, though the dataset encompasses 4115 lines, the Random Sample output does make sense (it's 206 lines), but the Stratified one does not (it always only outputs 43 lines, less than 1.5% of the total population size, not the 206 expected lines).

Comment: A crazy guess - if stratas of 20 items or less are common, many of them will have zero elements selected. Also, selecting the same **share** from each group is not exactly a stratified sample

Comment: Thanks! And it's indeed the case! So... How should I go around this?

Comment: I'd probably assign weights to each sample, 1/n_i where n_i is the corresponding group size, and then use df.sample

Comment: I am using an already defined strata (NombreDeEstrato) and I understood the "apply(lambda x:x.sample(frac=TamañoMuestral)" does the stratified portion.

Still, the fact that I'm getting too small strata is the issue here! Thanks again!